# Create database play java evolutions

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.5, playframework-evolutions, deadbolt-2

I am using play java 2.5.
I have created a database with following java code.

```
public OnStartup() throws SQLException {
    //demo create database with java code
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root&password=12345678");
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    int Result = s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE recruit3");
}
```

Module:

```
public class OnStartupModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(OnStartup.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

application.conf:

```
play.modules {
    enabled += "be.objectify.deadbolt.java.DeadboltModule"
    enabled += modules.CustomDeadboltHook
    enabled += modules.OnStartupModule 
}

default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recruit3"
default.username=root
default.password="12345678"
```

My question is, why running the web-app creating

```
error Cannot connect to database [default]
```

How to fix that, if I don't want to create the database with mysql workbench.

Any suggestion or cannot do this, please tell me.
Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as moving your database keys to the `db.default` namespace, you should be injecting `Database` into `OnStartup` to access the database configured with those properties.

First, add Play's JDBC support to `build.sbt`.

```
libraryDependencies += javaJdbc
```

If you're already running activator, make sure you use the `reload` command to pick up the changes to the build.

Update your `application.conf` to place the database configuration into the correct namespace.

```
db {
  default {
    driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recruit3"
    username=root
    password="12345678"
  }    
}
```

Finally, update `OnStartup` to receive a `Database` object that will be injected by Play.

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import play.db.Database;

public class OnStartup {

    @Inject
    public OnStartup(final Database db) throws SQLException {
        db.withConnection((Connection conn) -> {
            final Statement s = con.createStatement();
            return s.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE recruit3");
        });
    }
}
```

This allows you to configure the database one time, in `application.conf`, instead of hard-coding DB configuration into a class.

You can find more information [here](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaDatabase).

Answer (score 0):

Your database keys start with `default` instead of `db.default`. The correct syntax is something like this:

```
db {
    default {
        driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/recruit3"
        username=root
        password="12345678"
    }    
}
```

You already made your class as eager singleton, so it should work

Comment: problem seem not in code, because when i try connect with exists database, application no problem, play load application try connect database default before module OnStartupModule? I don't know about this. Thanks for comment.